# SQL Percentage Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to present a quick report of employee presenters and their client classroom attendance percentages, and I'm trying to figure out the correct query in SQL (for SQL Server).

Clients are scheduled individually for classes, so in table tSchedule, every row has a class name, the time and date of the class, a client name, the class presenter's name, and the client's attendance status (e.g., 'present', 'absent', 'absent w/ excuse','late', etc.)

So I need a SQL query that will output one row for each presenter, with the total number of clients that were scheduled in that presenter's classes within a given date range, the total number who actually showed up (i.e., with an attendance status of 'present' or 'absent w/excuse'), and what percent of the total those "present or excused" clients represent.

Adding in some details per replies below:

```
tSchedule

class            class_date     Employee_id     client_id       attendance_status
Basket Weaving   2017-07-13     231             712             Present
Basket Weaving   2017-07-13     231             121             Present
Basket Weaving   2017-07-13     231             186             Absent
Basket Weaving   2017-07-13     231             666             Absent
Juggling         2017-07-13     900             111             Present
Juggling         2017-07-13     900             222             Present
Juggling         2017-07-13     900             333             Present
Juggling         2017-07-13     900             712             Absent w/Excuse



Expected Result of Query:

Employee_id Clients Scheduled   Clients Present or Excused  Attendance Rate
231         4                   2                           50%
900         4                   4                           100%
```

(Addendum)
 Okay, the query I've ended up using (below) works, but it's ugly and I'm sure not ideal. If anyone knows the most elegant way to get the same results, I'd much appreciate. (@param1 and @param2 are user-entered dates for start and end dates of desired timespan)

```
Select
   pl.emp_id
   ,e.last_name + ', ' + e.first_name as facilitator
   ,count(pl.emp_id) as total_Count
   ,(select count(*) from planner where emp_id = pl.emp_id
       and visit_status in ('ARRIVED', 'PRESENT WITH JS', 'PRESENT NO JS')
       and plan_date >= @param1
       and plan_date <= @param2) as attended_Count
   ,cast(cast((select count(*) from planner where emp_id = pl.emp_id
       and visit_status in ('ARRIVED', 'PRESENT WITH JS','PRESENT NO JS')
       and plan_date >= @param1
       and plan_date <= @param2) as float) / cast((select count(*) from
       planner where emp_id = pl.emp_id
       and plan_date >= @param1
       and plan_date <= @param2) as float) * 100 as decimal (18,2)) as attendance_percent
from planner pl inner join employees e on pl.emp_id = e.emp_id
where pl.program_id = 2
    and pl.visittype_id in (42,173)
    and plan_date >=@param1
    and plan_date <= @param2
group by pl.emp_id, e.last_name + ', ' + e.first_name
```

Comment: Add sample data,expected result and the query you have tried so far

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ You have enough rep around here to know this question is lacking any relevant information.

Comment: Please show schema details, some sample data, then show us what you have tried, it's the best way to learn.

Comment: Added in some sample data and expected result to the question. The query I've started with works, but it's incomplete. All it tells me is total number of clients scheduled with each employee, a basic count/group by query: Select sch.emp_id, e.last_name + ', ' + e.first_name as facilitator, count(sch.emp_id) as totalCount from tSchedule sch inner join employees e on sch.emp_id = e.emp_id where class_date >='2017-07-01' and class_date <= '2017-07-15' group by sch.emp_id, e.last_name + ', ' + e.first_name

Comment: Please add that query into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    status,
    cnt*100.0/total
from 
(select c status,count(*) cnt from attendance c group by c.status),
(select count(*)total from attendance c)
```

Comment: Why the sub queries? BTW... you are missing aliases.

Comment: @scsimon: if you can do it without subqueries, do please present your own answer. Perhaps though once the OP has edited in their own attempt into the question... `:-)`.

Comment: @halfer this query will fail... as in it won't run. period. There are multiple syntax issues.

Comment: Ah, I am glad I made a comment in that case @scsimon, as it was not clear. "It will fail / it won't run" is much clearer `:-)`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.